# Editor toolbar and code in lists

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

When I type a question where I want a code block to appear as part of a list entry, I would start typing something like

```
 - abcd

 code;

 - efgh
```

and then select the "code" and press Ctrl-K or click on the corresponding button. However this gives me

```
 - abcd

     code;

 - efgh
```

which is displayes as

> - abcd
>
>   code;
> - efgh

But should be

```
 - abcd

        code;

 - efgh
```

displayed as

> - abcd
>
>   ```
>   code;
>   ```
> - efgh

I.e. I'm suggesting that the editor would add the necessary 7 more spaces instead of 4 needed outside of lists.